# Backpropagation through time - Gradient Calculation

Tags: vector-analysis, machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks

I think I got it right after reading multiple resources:

$W_h$ is the hiddel weight matrix

$W_i$ is the input weight matrix

$W_o$ is the output weight matrix

The simples one should be for $W_o$
$$
\displaylines{
 \frac{ \partial E } { \partial \mathbf{W}_o} 
= 
 \frac{1}{T}
 \sum^T_{t=1}
 \frac{ \partial L(\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>},\mathbf{y}^{<t>}) } { \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>}} 
 \frac{ \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>}} { \partial \mathbf{W}_o} 
}
$$
For for $W_h$ i got this:
$$
\displaylines{
 \frac{ \partial E } { \partial \mathbf{W}_h } 
= 
 \frac{ 1 }{ T }
 \sum^T_{t=1}
  \frac{ \partial L(\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>},\mathbf{y}^{<t>}) } { \partial \mathbf{W}_h }
\\=
 \frac{ 1 }{ T }
 \sum^T_{t=1}
  \frac{ \partial L(\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>},\mathbf{y}^{<t>}) } { \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>} }
  \frac{ \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>}      } { \partial \mathbf{h}^{<t>}  } 
  \frac{ \partial \mathbf{h}^{<t>}       } { \partial \mathbf{W}_h  } 
\\=
 \frac{ 1 }{ T }
 \sum^T_{t=1}
  \frac{ \partial L(\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>},\mathbf{y}^{<t>}) } { \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>} }
  \frac{ \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>}      } { \partial \mathbf{h}^{<t>}  } 
  \sum_{k=0}^t
  \left(
   \left(
    \prod_{s=k}^{t-1} \frac{ \partial \mathbf{h}^{<s+1>} } { \partial \mathbf{h}^{<s>} }
            \right) \frac{ \partial \mathbf{h}^{<k>}      } { \partial\mathbf{W}_h} \right)}$$

For $W_i$ it would be the same as for $W_h$
$$
\displaylines{
 \frac{ \partial E } { \partial \mathbf{W}_i} 
= 
 \frac{ 1 }{ T }
 \sum^T_{t=1}
  \frac{ \partial L(\hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>},\mathbf{y}^{<t>}) } { \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>} }
  \frac{ \partial \hat{\mathbf{y}}^{<t>}      } { \partial \mathbf{h}^{<t>}  } 
  \sum_{k=0}^t
  \left(
   \left(
    \prod_{s=k}^{t-1} \frac{ \partial \mathbf{h}^{<s+1>} } { \partial \mathbf{h}^{<s>} }
            \right)
   \frac{ \partial \mathbf{h}^{<k>}      } { \partial \mathbf{W}_h } 
  \right)}
$$

Here is an image of my thought for reference:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0TKh.png